# Display a list in leaflet popup

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

I want to display an unorderd list or table in a leaflet popup.
The number of items and their content are different and depend on the type of element which was clicked. 

So ideally the popup content should be created on the click event.

I tried to build the list inside the bindPopup function, but it's not working.

```
      L.marker([mapElement.y * -1, mapElement.x], {
      uniqueID: mapElement.elementID,
      mapIconWidth: mapElement.width,
      icon: new mapIcon({
        iconUrl: icon.mapIcon.imageData,
        iconSize: [elementSize, elementSize]
      })
    })
      .addTo(markers)
      .bindPopup(mapElement.element.nbr + ' ' + mapElement.element.name +  "<br/<ul>  <li v-for='state in mapElement.element.states'>{{ state.definition.stateTypeTitle }}</li> </ul>");
```

That's the output:

[image]

Any ideas would be great! 
Thanks!

---

Edited code (get this error message: **You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.**):

```
LoadMarker(mapID) {
  console.log("Load Markers");
  map.removeLayer(markers);
  markers.clearLayers();

  fetch(this.$apiUrl + "/mapelements/" + mapID)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(received => {
      let mapElements = received;
      let mapZoom = map.getZoom();

      mapElements.forEach(function(mapElement) {
        let elementSize = (mapElement.width / 8) * mapZoom;


          let popup = new Vue({
          template:
            mapElement.element.nbr +
            " " +
            mapElement.element.name +
            "<br/<ul>  <li v-for='state in mapElement.element.states'>{{ state.definition.stateTypeTitle }}</li> </ul>",
          data: {
            mapElement
          }
        }).$mount().$el;


        let icon = mapIconSchemas.find(
          schema => schema.mapIconSchemaID == mapElement.mapIconSchemaID
        );
        if (icon != null) {
          L.marker([mapElement.y * -1, mapElement.x], {
            uniqueID: mapElement.elementID,
            mapIconWidth: mapElement.width,
            icon: new mapIcon({
              iconUrl: icon.mapIcon.imageData,
              iconSize: [elementSize, elementSize]
            })
          })
            .addTo(markers)
            .bindPopup(popup);
        }
      });
    });

  map.addLayer(markers);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution, if you want to use the **vue templating engine** to fill the popup content.

I explained it for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696928/how-can-i-integrate-a-vue-component-in-a-leaflet-popup/56699952#56699952).

You create a component with the content you want to display in the popup, but you hide it :

```
<my-popup-content v-show=False ref='foo'><my-popup-content>
```

Then you can access the generated html of that component in your code like this :

```
const template = this.$refs.foo.$el.innerHTML
```

and use it to fill your popup.

The big advantage of that method is that you can generate the popup content with all the vue functionalities (v-if, v-bind, whatever) and you don't need messy string concatenations anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use Vue templating syntax in the HTML String for the popup. But as can be seen from the docs the `.bindPopup` method can also accept HTML element. So your way to go would be like this:

first create the popup element:

```
let popup = new Vue({
    template: mapElement.element.nbr + ' ' + mapElement.element.name +  "<br/<ul>  <li v-for='state in mapElement.element.states'>{{ state.definition.stateTypeTitle }}</li> </ul>",
    data: {
        mapElement
    }
}).$mount().$el
```

and then use it in the `.bindPopup` method:

```
/*...*/
.bindPopup(popup)
```

Comment: Hi Slim! Thank you for your reply! Where do I create this popup element? If I try to create it inside my component, I will get an "Vue is not defined" error. Sorry for the silly question. I'm new to vue.

Comment: Well, simply import Vue in your component; `import Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: Hi. Thanks again! I have updated my question. I don't get it running. Could you help me one more time?

Comment: The error you get is clear. You either need to import vue build that includes the compiler or use render function instead of template for the popup component. The easiest way is to create a separate .vue file for that component and import it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but I can't understand your answer @Slim

Answer (score 0):

```
import Component from './Component.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
bindPopup(() => new Vue({
  // router,
  // store,
  render: h => h(Component)
}).$mount().$el)
```

perfect

Comment: Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution.