# How can I integrate a Vue component in a leaflet popup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

My project uses Vue.js and leaflet to display some data on a map, in the shape of markers.

The markers on the map are bound popups, which content I would like to be reactively updated when the associated data change, just like any Vue component does.

I checked the option of [vueleaflet](https://github.com/brandonxiang/vueleaflet), which provides a popup component for leaflet. But this script defines the content of the popup though an attribute of the component: `<l-popup content="a popup"></l-popup>`. This way isn't so relevant in my case, as I have some complex templating to insert in the popup (including conditional statements and subcomponents).

I would rather need something like:

```
<l-popup>
  My elaborate content here.
</l-popup>
```

Comment: It is effectively a duplicate, but I find this title better (more explicit and generic) than the other. Good job finding it :)

Comment: Indeed. I noticed this post, but didn't pay sufficient attention, because of the title. Sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

I advise you to use **[vue2-leaflet](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet)** instead.

It has a popup component that behaves the way you describe. See [here](https://korigan.github.io/Vue2Leaflet/#/components/l-popup/).

[image]

There is also **another solution**, if you don't want to use a package to do the link between vue and leaflet. It's almost a trick.

You create your elaborate content in a component, but you hide it :

```
<my-elaborate-popup-content v-show=False ref='foo'><my-elaborate-popup-content>
```

Then you can access the generated html of that component in your code like this :

```
const template = this.$refs.foo.$el.innerHTML
```

and use it to fill your popup !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. vue2-leaflet seems great. However, I ended up with a lighter solution, very close from your second suggestion. I create my popup contents in a component, and hide it with v-show. But I don't use its innerHTML as a template. I directly use the element, as leaflet allows. `myMarker.bindPopup(()=>()=>this.$refs.foo.$el)` This way, I benefit of all Vue features: reactivity, events, etc.