# Using a Vue3 component as a Leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696928/how-can-i-integrate-a-vue-component-in-a-leaflet-popup) shows how we can use a Vue2 component as the content of a LeafletJS popup. I've been unable to get this working with Vue3.

Extracting the relevant section of my code, I have:

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import L, { type Content } from 'leaflet'
import type { FeatureCollection, Feature } from 'geojson'

import LeafletPopup from '@/components/LeafletPopup.vue'

// This ref will be matched by Vue to the element with the same ref name
const popupDialogElement = ref(null)

function addFeaturePopup(feature:Feature, layer:L.GeoJSON) {
  if (popupDialogElement?.value !== null) {
    const content:Content = popupDialogElement.value as HTMLElement
    layer.bindPopup(() => content.$el)
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="map-container">
    <section id="map">
    </section>
    <leaflet-popup ref="popupDialogElement" v-show="false">
    </leaflet-popup>
  </div>
</template>
```

This does produce a popup when I click on the map, but it has no content.

If, instead, I change line 14 to:

```ts
    layer.bindPopup(() => content.$el.innerHTML)
```

then I **do** get a popup with the HTML markup I expect, but unsurprisingly I lose all of the Vue behaviours I need (event handling, etc).

Inspecting the `addFeaturePopup` function in the JS debugger, the `content` does seem to be an instance of `HTMLElement`, so I'm not sure why it's not working to pass it to Leaflet's `bindPopup` method. I assume this has something to do with how Vue3 handles references, but as yet I can't see a way around it.

### Update 2022-06-09

As requested, here's the `console.log` output: I've put it in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/ijdickinson/6568642dc574038ecc7f4393b6745d00) as it's quite long

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(content.$el)` right above your `bindPopup` function?

Comment: I've added a gist with the console.log output

Comment: As I see in your gist, your element has `style="display: none;"`. It might be why your content does not appear on the popup.

Comment: Yes, that would be a consequence of the `v-show="false"`. But that's the recommendation from the previous question I referenced: in order to use the `$el` DOM node as the popup, it has to be in the DOM somewhere. The difference between `v-show` and `v-if` is that show will actually render the node, but then hide it. So *maybe" there's a difference between `v-show` in Vue2 vs. Vue3, but if so I'm not sure what that could be

Comment: @Duannx But that was a good hint: if I add a CSS rule to forcefully override the `display:none` inside `.leaflet-popup-content`, I get the node to show up and have Vue behaviours. Hurrah!

Comment: Glad you find the solution. Btw, there is no difference between v-show in Vue2 vs. Vue3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to document the solution I ended up using, I needed to add an additional style rule in addition to the general skeleton outlined in the question:

```vue
<style>
.leaflet-popup-content >* {
  display: block !important;
}
</style>
```

This overrides the `display:none` that is attached to the DOM node by `v-show=false`. It would be nice not to need the `!important`, but I wasn't able to make the rule selective enough in my experiments.